# What is the missing number? From this table

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

I am trying to solve this question but I can't. Can you please help me to find the missing number.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c}10 & 35 & 7\\\hline&2\end{array}$, $\begin{array}{c|c|c}15&?&8\\\hline&12\end{array}$

The given options are $360,370,375$ or $380$.

10 is not the answer, and the correct ans is 360 but how? Thanks in advance.!  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSWpY.jpg

Comment: Puzzles like this are often ambiguous.  There are infinitely many answers with little reason to suspect one is "more correct" than another with any such distinction between answers being based on personal opinion.

Comment: Now you told the correct solution, people will be giving you answers that result=360. it would have been fun if you kept it to yourself

Comment: To answer these kind of questions usually context matters. What was the title of the chapter, or what kind of other question precede/follow it?

Comment: Are you sure  it is $12$, under the question mark?

Comment: The first comment hits the nail on the head. Therefore, users should not answer such questions because they are off-topic. Without the necessary context the logic behind such questions can only be guessed. This site is for helping people out of problems in mathematics, this question rather belongs to puzzle stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I found an algorithm.

Define \begin{array}{c|c|c}
a & x & c \\
\hline
& b\end{array}
as a relation where $x=f(a,b,c)=\dfrac{abc}{4}$.  We can see that for $f(10,2,7)$, we have $x=\dfrac{10\cdot2\cdot7}{4}=35$ as desired.

Therefore, for $f(15,12,8)$, we have $x=\dfrac{15\cdot12\cdot8}{4}=360$.

Comment: This answer is not meant to be taken as the letter of the law; if I had the enthusiasm I would surely have come up with a more absurd relation between the numbers.

Comment: that was actually clever.